# Embed Python/C API in a multi-threading C++ program

Tags: python, c++, multithreading

I am trying to embed Python in a C++ multi-threading program using the Python/C API (version 3.7.3) on a quad-core ARM 64 bit architecture. A dedicated thread-safe class "PyHandler" takes care of all the Python API calls:

```
class PyHandler
{
 public:
        PyHandler();
        ~PyHandler();
        bool run_fun();
        // ...
 private:
        PyGILState_STATE _gstate;
        std::mutex _mutex;
}
```

In the *constructor* I initialize the Python interpreter:

```
PyHandler::PyHandler()
{
    Py_Initialize();

    //PyEval_SaveThread(); // UNCOMMENT TO MAKE EVERYTHING WORK !
}
```

And in the *destructor* I undo all initializations:

```
PyHandler::~PyHandler()
{
    _gstate = PyGILState_Ensure();

    if (Py_IsInitialized()) // finalize python interpreter
        Py_Finalize();
}
```

Now, in order to make ***run_fun()*** callable by one thread at a time, I use the mutex variable *_mutex* (see below). On top of this, I call *PyGILState_Ensure()* to make sure the current thread holds the python GIL, and call *PyGILState_Release()* at the end to release it. All the remaining python calls happen within these two calls:

```
bool PyHandler::run_fun()
{
      std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lockGuard(_mutex);

      _gstate = PyGILState_Ensure(); // give the current thread the Python GIL

      // Python calls...

      PyGILState_Release(_gstate); // release the Python GIL till now assigned to the current thread

      return true;
}
```

Here is how the main() looks like:

```
int main()
{
      PyHandler py; // constructor is called !

      int n_threads = 10;
      std::vector<std::thread> threads;

      for (int i = 0; i < n_threads; i++)
            threads.push_back(std::thread([&py]() { py.run_fun(); }));

      for (int i = 0; i < n_threads; i++)
            if (threads[i].joinable())
                  threads[i].join();
}
```

Although all precautions, the program always deadlocks at the *PyGILState_Ensure()* line in *run_fun()* during the very first attempt. **BUT** when I uncomment the line with *PyEval_SaveThread()* in the constructor **everything magically works**. Why is that ?

Notice that I am not calling *PyEval_RestoreThread()* anywhere. Am I supposed to use the macros *Py_BEGIN_ALLOW_THREADS* and *Py_END_ALLOW_THREADS* instead ? I thought these macros and *PyEval_SaveThread()* are only used dealing with Python threads and NOT with non-Python threads, as in my case! Am I missing something ?

The [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/init.html#non-python-created-threads) for my case, only mentions the use of *PyGILState_Ensure()* and *PyGILState_Release*. Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: You'll need to include an actual [mcve]. A lot of this will depend on the scope of `_gstate` and your actual control flow around `PyGILState_Release`. It's likely that you're using `PyGILState_Check` incorrectly (you shouldn't be using it at all), but the details are impossible to verify with the information you've posted.

Comment: Thanks Sneftel, I added more details as well as a successfull attempt I came about this morning